# Adding two array objects with operator overloading resulting in segmentation fault

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers, segmentation-fault, operator-overloading

I'm setting up a class in c++ that will have array objects and a function to add them together (by adding their individual components). Each of these objects has a pointer to a 'new' array of floats which will be added together. I believe that either because these are pointers or are assigned to 'new' arrays, there is some sort of memory issue when accessing their components through the overloaded + operator, but I'm not sure what specifically is the issue. The file compiles without any issues but simply says "Segmentation fault (core dumped)" when run. Also I'm aware I should be using a min value rather than max in the for loop but right now all my arrays are the same size so I'm just testing it this way.

If I comment out the actual addition of the arrays in main(), the error message completely disappears, but I'm not quite sure why.

```
#include  <iostream>

using namespace std;

class Array
{

private:
   int size, location;
   float value;

public:
   float *arrayptr;

Array(int size)
{
   arrayptr = new float[size];
}

void setValue(int location, float value)
{
   arrayptr[location] = value;
}

Array operator+(Array a)
{
   int max;

   if (a.size >= size)
   {
      max = a.size;
   }
   else
   {
      max = size;
   }

   Array tmparray(max);

   for(int i=0; i<max; i++)
   {
      tmparray.arrayptr[i] = a.arrayptr[i] + arrayptr[i];
   }
   return tmparray;
}

};

main()
{
   Array a1(3);
   a1.setValue(0, 1.0);
   a1.setValue(1, 22.0);
   a1.setValue(2, 12.2);

   Array a2(3);
   a2.setValue(0, 3.3);
   a2.setValue(1, 44.5);
   a2.setValue(2, 21.7);

   Array tmp(3);
   // Source of the error (parenthesis doesn't seem to affect it):
   tmp = (a1 + a2);

}
```

Comment: That said, if you add a destructor that `delete`s the float array you'll definitely get into trouble due to the the lack of a copy constructor and `operator=`.

Comment: Are you familiar with deep and shallow copies?

Comment: This is actually all my code, it's pretty basic right now. I commented out just another operator overloading function that I'm working on, but it has no interaction with the rest of the code. Also I'm not sure what deep and shallow copies are, should I learn that?

Answer (score 2):

You don't set size in the constructor, so when `if (a.size >= size)` happens, you get undefined behavior. Probably gets set to some ludicrous value and you walk off the array.

`m_size = size` Set the member size value to the size value passed into the constructor.

The + operator also doesn't watch out for walking off the array when the arrays are not the same size.

Answer (score 1):

You had not Initialize size variable.

You need to Initialize it.

```
Array(int _size)
{
    size = _size;
    arrayptr = new float[size];
}
```

And your size variable is private.

So, it can't reference. So size variable need to declare as public.

Comment: @GirishTiwari And, you need to delete array in destructor. I will be serious trouble sometimes.